# javax.net.ssl.SSLException in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I see these errors in system logs for the passive DC nodes, where the nodes in the Error messages are from the other DC which is active. In active DC I don't see such errors.

Could this be connectivity issues ? Is this pointing to something serious issue with my cluster?

How can I debug my problem?

```
ERROR [MessagingService-Incoming-/123.12.13.1] 2024-02-19 10:07:57,692 CassandraDaemon.java:244 - Exception in thread Thread[MessagingService-Incoming-/123.12.13.1,5,main]
java.io.IOError: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset
ERROR [MessagingService-Incoming-/123.12.13.2] 2024-02-19 10:07:57,692 CassandraDaemon.java:244 - Exception in thread Thread[MessagingService-Incoming-/123.12.13.2,5,main]
java.io.IOError: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset
```

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert, but related articles (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507878/ssl-connection-reset) seem to indicate that a good place to start troubleshooting would be to verify that everything is working properly with SSL/TLS. Try verifying that your SSL configurations are set to work at the proper protocol level and view this article under "TLS/SSL Encryption"

https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/stable/cassandra/operating/security.html